# Selected messages in a JSF dataTable don't get updated as selected in Java

Tags: jsf, datatable

So I have this problem: I have a dataTable that is being generated in JSF using a list from the Bean of its corresponding XHTML page. My dataTable and the column with the checkboxes that you select the messages with looks like this:

```
<t:dataTable binding="#{table}" rendered="#{searchArhivaUIBean.renderTable}" value="#{searchArhivaUIBean.nonEdiAbstractList}" var="dataItem" border="0" cellspacing="2" width="100%" id="tdtbl" rows="#{searchArhivaUIBean.numberOfRows}" headerClass="tableHeader" rowClasses="rowOdd,rowEven" columnClasses="Column">

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAllCheckbox" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this.id,'form2:tdtbl')" 
        value="#{searchArhivaUIBean.selectAllCheckbox}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <t:panelGroup>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{dataItem.selectat}"/>
    </t:panelGroup>
</h:column>
```

In my Java file, I try to get the selected items from the dataTable and use them to generate files (an archive) with the ones selected. The problem is - none of them get selected. If you run a for loop to see which ones get selected as you check the checkboxes in the interface and then press the button to download the generated archive, I get that all the messages have their boolean value of "selected", with the getter method "isSelected()" set to false.

Here's some of my Java code:

```
try {
        // lista documente de pus in zip
        Map<String, byte[]> fisiere = new HashMap<>();
        File fileZip = null;

        if (tipMesaj.equals(TipMsg6Char.ORDERS)) {

            System.out.println(formatulMesajului);

            fileZip = new File("lista_de_comenzi.zip");

            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++){
                System.out.println(nonEdiAbstractList.get(i).isSelectat());
            }

            for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {

                NonEdiOrder msg = (NonEdiOrder) nonEdiAbstractList.get(i);
                System.out.println("Am trecut peste lista " + i);
                if (msg.isSelectat()){...}
```

Basically, the first for loop will display "false" for all the elements, and then obviously the if(msg.isSelectat()) will never execute because isSelectat returns false for all the elements.

How can I make the behavior of checking the checkboxes to set the value of "selectat" to true, so that when I use "isSelectat()" for each object, to return true for the ones that I've checked in the interface?

Thanks!